# django-filter use paginations

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-filter

I'm using the [`django-filter`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter#django-filter) package to provide a search functionality on my List View.

Now I want to add a pagination to that view as well.
 
I'm trying to combine pagination to a filtered queryset, but I have no clue on how to go on.

So far, I have tried the following on `views.py`:

```
def search(request):
    qs = local_url.objects.filter(global_url__id=1).all()
    paginator = Paginator(qs, 25)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        pub = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        pub = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
       pub = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    url_filter = PublicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return render(request, 'ingester/search_list.html', {'filter': url_filter, 'publication':pub})
```

Comment: Have you created the html template for pagination?

Comment: Yes, I left it out in my example because my main problem is how to combine  Filterset Object with the Paginator in my view .

Comment: Hey @AnhTuanNguyen did you find any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use Django Filter and paginate the filtered result you can do the following:

1. Create a filter class for your model:

   On `my_project/my_app/filters.py`:

   ```
   import django_filters

   class MyModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
       class Meta:
           model = MyModel
           # Declare all your model fields by which you will filter
           # your queryset here:
           fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', ...]
   ```
2. Every `FilterSet` object has a `.qs` property which contains the **filtered queryset** and you can even [override it if you want](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs).
3. We will paginate the `.qs` property of our `MyModelFilter`:

   On `my_project/my_app/views.py`:

   ```
   from . import filters
   from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

   def my_view(request):
       # BTW you do not need .all() after a .filter() 
       # local_url.objects.filter(global_url__id=1) will do
       filtered_qs = filters.MyModelFilter(
                         request.GET, 
                         queryset=MyModel.objects.all()
                     ).qs
       paginator = Paginator(filtered_qs, YOUR_PAGE_SIZE)

       page = request.GET.get('page')
       try:
           response = paginator.page(page)
       except PageNotAnInteger:
           response = paginator.page(1)
       except EmptyPage:
           response = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

       return render(
           request, 
           'your_template.html', 
           {'response': response}
       )
   ```

And there you have it!

---

**PS_1:** Django filter in my experience, ["plays" better with Django Rest Framework](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/rest_framework.html#integration-with-drf).

**PS_2:** If you are about to utilize DRF, I have written an example on how to use pagination in a function based view which you can easily combine with a `FilterSet`:

```
@api_view(['GET',])
def my_function_based_list_view(request):
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    filtered_set = filters.MyModelFilter(
                       request.GET, 
                       queryset=MyModel.objects.all()
                   ).qs
    context = paginator.paginate_queryset(filtered_set, request)
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(context, many=True)
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: could you or someone add a html template, I'm trying to get this to work, but I'm stuck at the template.

Comment: @GaryNobles This a fine place to start: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/ and this tutorial will help you a lot: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_templates/

Comment: I keep reading them, I'll read again, I have the pagination working, but I can't get the filtering to work. I have 
{{ filter.material.label_tag }}
{% render_field filter.form.material %}
I'm really stuck on this and I have a deadline for Monday.

Comment: @GaryNobles Without a good look at your code, nobody can help. I would advise you to compose a new question if you are that badly stuck :/

Comment: Unfortunately I can no longer post questions, even with a reputation of 116, and I'm dyslexic so I ask things in non normal ways. Anyway, I have used this code, I have it half working but I just can't figure out the filtering issue, this post looks like the most promising of all that I have seen, but a template example would help me understand how to implement it. I'm on a research project and if I can't get this up and running I'm going to have to resort to raw sql like last year. I didn't design the database, a redesign is scheduled for after the excavation.

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me: 
in my template instead of using this

```
<li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
```

I wrote this:

```
{% if 'whatever_parameter_you_use_to_filter' in request.get_full_path %}
   <li><a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ i }}"{{ i }}</a></li>
{% else %}
   <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: The only issue is, like @DonExo said in his answer, the page parameter is appended to the url. But it's working though.

Comment: The problem with this is you can't have more than 2 pages. Each time you will get full path from request you will find page=X and will be added.

Comment: This doesn't work when multiple parameters are being used to filter.

Answer (score 10):

To add to the answers, I did it with html tables too along with django-filters and Paginator. Below are my view and template files. The template tag is needed to make sure you pass the right parameters to the pagination url.

**search_view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app.models.filters_model import ApiStatusFilter
from app.models.api_status import ApiStatus
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def status(request):
    all_entries_ordered = ApiStatus.objects.values().order_by('-created_at')[:200]

    for dictionarys in all_entries_ordered:
        dictionarys

    apistatus_list = ApiStatus.objects.values().order_by('-created_at')
    apistatus_filter = ApiStatusFilter(request.GET, queryset=apistatus_list)

    paginator = Paginator(apistatus_filter.qs, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        dataqs = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        dataqs = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        dataqs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'status_page_template.html', {'dictionarys': dictionarys, 'apistatus_filter': apistatus_filter, 'dataqs': dataqs, 'allobjects': apistatus_list})
```

**status_template.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load my_templatetags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/table_styling.css' %}">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>

    <body>
         <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for keys in dictionarys.keys %} 
                        <th>{{ keys }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <form method="get">
                    {{ apistatus_filter.form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                        {% for user in dataqs.object_list %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.date_time }}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.log }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                </form>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="pagination">
            <span>
                {% if dataqs.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?{% query_transform request page=1 %}">&laquo; first</a>
                    <a href="?{% query_transform request page=dataqs.previous_page_number %}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}

                <span class="current">
                    Page {{ dataqs.number }} of {{ dataqs.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>

                {% if dataqs.has_next %}
                    <a href="?{% query_transform request page=dataqs.next_page_number %}">next</a>
                    <a href="?{% query_transform request page=dataqs.paginator.num_pages %}">last &raquo;</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**my_templatetags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def query_transform(request, **kwargs):
    updated = request.GET.copy()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        if v is not None:
            updated[k] = v
        else:
            updated.pop(k, 0)

    return updated.urlencode()
```

Answer (score 7):

It took me some time to find the DRYer and cleaner solution to fix this issue and the best one, in my opinion, is the one using template tags.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def relative_url(value, field_name, urlencode=None):
    url = '?{}={}'.format(field_name, value)
    if urlencode:
        querystring = urlencode.split('&')
        filtered_querystring = filter(lambda p: p.split('=')[0] != field_name, querystring)
        encoded_querystring = '&'.join(filtered_querystring)
        url = '{}&{}'.format(url, encoded_querystring)
    return url
```

and in your template

```
<a href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
```

Source: [Dealing With QueryString Parameters](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html)

Answer (score 4):

The most important part here is the **how you construct your URLs in the template**.

you probably have

```
{% if pages.has_previous %}
<li><a href="?page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

which is perfectly fine if you are using only it for switching between the initial paginated results.

But the tricky part is when you use the `django-fitler` filters, the querystring (that part after the **'?'**) gets totally new key-values pairs, disregarding your `?page=2` or similar.

So to make pagination work with filtered results, when you click the "Next" or "Prev" button - among the key-values from `django-fitler` you also need to pass the `&page=5` as pair.

As @stathoula mentioned, you need to check if at least one of your filter fields is already present in the querystring. If it is, then you need to use the already present key-value pairs, followed by the new `&page=3` pair.

It seems very simple, but I had to done small hackish not to repeat the `&page=1` over and over again within the querystring as a user is clicking trough the arrows.

In my case I'm having 'title' as a filter, so I need to check if it's already present there.

Here's a snippet of what I've made working perfectly fine for my project.

**templates/pagination.html**

```
<div class="paginator">

    {% with request.get_full_path as querystring %}
        <ul class="pagination nav navbar-nav">

            <!-- Previous page section -->
            {% if pages.has_previous %}
                {% if 'title' in querystring %}
                    {% if 'page' in querystring %}
                        <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                            <a href="{{ querystring|slice:":-7" }}&page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                            <a href="{{ querystring }}&page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                        <a href="?page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            <!-- All pages section -->
            {% for page in pages.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if 'title' in querystring %}
                    {% if 'page' in querystring %}
                        <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                            <a href="{{ querystring|slice:":-7" }}&page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                            <a href="{{ querystring }}&page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                        <a href="?page={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            <!-- Next page section -->
            {% if pages.has_next %}
                {% if 'title' in querystring %}
                    {% if 'page' in querystring %}
                        <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                            <a href="{{ querystring|slice:":-7" }}&page={{ pages.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                            <a href="{{ querystring }}&page={{ pages.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    <li class="paginator {% if pages.number == page %}active{% endif %}">
                        <a href="?page={{ pages.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

        </ul>
    {% endwith %}

</div>
```

Here is the view, just in case:

**app/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    condo_list = Condo.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp_created')
    condo_filter = CondoFilter(request.GET, queryset=condo_list)

    paginator = Paginator(condo_filter.qs, MAX_CONDOS_PER_PAGE)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        condos = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        condos = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        condos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {
        'title': 'Home',
        'condos': condos,
        'page': page,
        'condo_filter': condo_filter,
    })
```

Here's a working example:

[image].

Comment: With more than 9 pages, the slice won't work perfectly. But there are already enough conditions in this template and the purpose of a filter is to reduce the page number so it shouldn't be necessary to change this.

Answer (score 4):

My approach for "remember filter/query URL parameters" for paginated results: passing the current URL parameters as a context variable:

```py
# views.py

class PublicationFilterView(FilterView):
    model = Publication
    filterset_class = PublicationFilter
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _request_copy = self.request.GET.copy()
        parameters = _request_copy.pop('page', True) and _request_copy.urlencode()
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['parameters'] = parameters
        return context
```

```html
# templates/path/to/pagination.html

<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&{{ parameters }}">
  Next
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

this one works 100% with me

views.py:

```html
def search(request):
    
    category=Category.objects.all()
    try:
        qs=request.GET["qs"]
        products=Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=qs) |Q(details__icontains=qs) | Q(category__name__icontains=qs) | Q(branch__child__icontains=qs) | Q(manufacturer__name__icontains=qs) | Q(color__name__icontains=qs)).distinct()
        print(products)
        search=f"qs={qs}"
    except:
        search=None
```

and in HTML

```html
 <ul class="shop-p__pagination">
                                        {% if products.has_provious %}
                                        <li>

                                       <a class="fas fa-angle-left" href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}&{search}"></a></li>
                                       {% endif  %}
                                       {% for i in products.paginator.page_range %}
                                       {% if products.number == i %}
                                       
                                       <li class="is-active"><a href="?page={{i}}&{{search}}">{{i}}</a></li>
                                       {% else %}
                                       <li><a href="?page={{i}}&{{search}}">{{i}}</a></li>

                                       {% endif %}
                                     {% endfor %}
                               
                                       {% if products.has_next %}
                                   <li>

                                       <a class="fas fa-angle-right" href="?page={{ products.next_page_number }}&{{search}}"></a></li>
                                       {% endif %}
                                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you goal is to paginate your filtered query set. If so, you can pass "qs" property of PublicationFilter object to Paginator constructor:

```
def search(request):
    qs = local_url.objects.filter(global_url__id=1).all()
    url_filter = PublicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    paginator = Paginator(url_filter.qs, 25)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        pub = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        pub = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        pub = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    url_filter = PublicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return render(request, 'ingester/search_list.html', {'publication':pub})
```

**url_filter.qs** contains filtered QuerySet
**url_filter.queryset** contains non-filtered QuerySet

Answer (score 0):

- Simple & sweet,
- use this, `pip install filter-and-pagination`
- https://pypi.org/project/filter-and-pagination/

---

#### Implementation Step

1. install package by `pip install filter-and-pagination`
2. import FilterPagination by `from filter_and_pagination import FilterPagination` in view.py
3. in your function writte code as bellow standards...

```
queryset = FilterPagination.filter_and_pagination(request, Customer)
serialize_data = CustomerSerializer(queryset['queryset'], many=True).data
resultset = {'dataset': serialize_data, 'pagination': queryset['pagination']}
```

- in this code `Customer` is Django model &
- `CustomerSerializer` is a DRF Serializer class

4. in the resultset it contains dataset & pagination data, In this format (API Response) link: https://github.com/ashish1997it/filter-pagination-dj#demo
5. For the API request follow PostMan collection link: https://github.com/ashish1997it/filter-pagination-dj#postman in the header section it will take a parameter & request you customize as per your requirement

If you still face any difficulty then contact me :)

Comment: Hey, @AlexWinkler I addon Implementation Step in my answer, Go through it :)

Comment: Thanks for improving the documentation a bit but still no luck. Here's a SOF question I'm working on, I've tried the function-based view approach but made more progress so far as a class-based. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719277/filtering-and-pagination-with-django-class-based-views

Answer (score 0):

In `get_context_data()` function:

```
form_submitted = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' in self.request.GET
context['cleaned_full_path'] = '{}{}'.format(
    self.request.get_full_path().split('&page' if form_submitted else '?page')[0],
    '&' if form_submitted else '?'
)
```

Then, in your template, load in something like

`<a href="{{ cleaned_full_path }}page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}"`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @stathoula and in response to @Benbb96, I managed to erase the additional `page` parameters with a regular expression, overriding the `setup` method in the class based view:

```py
import re

...

class MyView(ListView):
...

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        request.GET.get("page")
        request.META["QUERY_STRING"] = re.sub("(&|\?)page=(.)*", "", request.META.get("QUERY_STRING", ""))
        return super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it helps anyone!

More info:

- [Request and Response Objects - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/)
- [as_view() - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)