# how can I use pagination with django_filter

Tags: django, filter, django-filter

I got a problem with pagination after using django_filter in my TemplateView.
Before use django_filter, my pagination was working normally but now it show all the items in every page, I've been looking on the internet but I didn't find a good solution for this.
how can I fix it?
thanks

my filter.py

```
class SnippetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    area = []
    tecnology = Technology.objects.values('parent_area').distinct().order_by('parent_area_id')
    for a in tecnology:                                                                         
        area.append(a['parent_area']) 

    parent_area = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=ApplicationArea.objects.filter(id__in=area), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Technology
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'kind', 'patent', 'patent_type', 'parent_area']
```

my view.py

```
class TechnologyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Technology
    template_name = "technology/technology.html"
    paginate_by = 9

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(TechnologyListView, self).get_queryset()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_staff:
            queryset = Technology.objects.all()
        elif self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_technology:
            queryset = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-id')
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        selected_elements = []
        data = super(TechnologyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_technology:
            data['finished'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, category=0).count()
            data['developed'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, category=1).count()
            data['product'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, kind=0).count()
            data['process'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, kind=1).count()
            data['software'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, kind=2).count()
            data['deposited'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, patent=0).count()
            data['licensed'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, patent=1).count()
            data['donthave'] = Technology.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, patent=2).count()
        elif self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_staff :          
            data['finished'] = Technology.objects.filter(category=0).count()
            data['developed'] = Technology.objects.filter(category=1).count()
            data['product'] = Technology.objects.filter(kind=0).count()
            data['process'] = Technology.objects.filter(kind=1).count()
            data['software'] = Technology.objects.filter(kind=2).count()
            data['deposited'] = Technology.objects.filter(patent=0).count()
            data['licensed'] = Technology.objects.filter(patent=1).count()
            data['dontthave'] = Technology.objects.filter(patent=2).count()

        data['filter'] = SnippetFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())

        return data
```

template.html

```
     <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row">        
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div style="margin-top:20%; margin-bottom:25% ">
                    <h1 class="title text-center">Filtro:</h1>
                    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'technology:tech_index' %}" novalidate>
                        {{filter.form|bootstrap}}

                        <a class="btn btn-rw btn-danger" href="{% url 'technology:tech_index' %}">Limpar Filtro</a>
                        <input type='submit' value='Procurar' class='btn btn-rw btn-primary'>                    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                <br>                  
                <a class="btn btn-rw btn-primary" href="{% url 'technology:create_tech' %}"><i class="fa fa-bolt">
                </i>Adicionar Tecnologia</a>                            


                <h1 class="title text-center">Minhas Tecnologias</h1>


                {% if filter.qs.count > 0 %}


                <div class="tab-content tab-shop mt15" style="align-items: center !important;">
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <canvas id="category"></canvas>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <canvas id="type" ></canvas>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <canvas id="patent"></canvas>
                        </div> 
                        <!-- <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <canvas id="area_ap" width="80" height="80"></canvas>
                        </div>   -->
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="tab-content tab-shop mt15">


                    <div id="home" class="tab-pane row fade in active">

                        {% for item in filter.qs %}        
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb30">
                            <div class="view  no-margin" style="background-color: #cfcfcf">
                                <!-- Blog Thumb -->
                                <div class="product-container">

                                    {% if item.area_img %}                                                      
                                    <img class="img-responsive full-width" style="width:100%; height:200px" src="{{item.area_img.image.url}}" alt="..."> 
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img class="img-responsive full-width" style="width:100%; height:200px" src="{% static 'images/notavailable.png' %}" alt="...">                                                
                                    {% endif %}                                                                                          

                                </div>
                                <div class="mask">
                                    <div class="image-hover-content">
                                            <!-- Zoom + Blog Link -->
                                            <a href="{% url 'technology:detail_tech' item.pk %}"  >
                                                <div class="image-icon-holder"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Visualizar" class="ion-eye image-icons"style="color:#fff"></span></div>
                                            </a>
                                            {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_technology %}                                                                                                      
                                                <a href="{% url 'technology:update_tech' item.pk %}">
                                                    <div class="image-icon-holder"><span  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar" class="ion-edit image-icons" style="color:#fff"></span></div>
                                                </a>
                                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-{{item.pk}}">
                                                    <div class="image-icon-holder"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Deletar" class="ion-ios7-trash image-icons" style="color:red"></span></div>
                                                </a>
                                                {% endif %}

                                                <div class="modal fade" id="delete-{{item.pk}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                        <div class="modal-content text-center">
                                                            <form action="{% url 'technology:delete_tech' pk=item.pk %}" method="post">
                                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                    <h2>Deletar</h2>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                                    <p>Você deseja realmente deletar "{{ item }}"?</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Voltar</button>
                                                            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Confirmar" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div><!-- /image hover content -->
                                    </div><!-- /mask-->
                                </div>
                                <div class="shop-product content-box-shadow">
                                    <a href="{% url 'technology:update_tech' item.pk %}"><h2>{{item.title}}</h2></a>
                                    {% if item.description %}                                          
                                        <p>{{item.description|truncatechars:40}}</p>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <p class="text-danger">Não há descrição</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
                        </li>
                            <li>
                                {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% include "includes/paginator.html" %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="tab-content tab-shop mt15 text-center " style="padding-top: 25%; padding-bottom: 25%">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 class="text-info">Nenhuma tecnologia cadastrada</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

paginator.html

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span class="page-link">&laquo; 
            </span></li>
        {% endif %}

         {% for page_num in paginator.page_range %}
             {% if page_obj.number == page_num %}
                 <li class="page-item active">
                    <span class="page-link">
                       {{ page_num }}
                       <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </span>
                 </li>
             {% elif page_num > page_obj.number|add:'-2' and page_num < page_obj.number|add:4 %}
                 <li class="page-item">
                     <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{page_num}}</a>
                 </li>
             {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}


          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
             <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
          {% else %}
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                  <span class="page-link">
            &raquo;
                  </span>
              </li>
          {% endif %}


    </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue for awhile, and found this solution to be my favourite.

django-filter's FilterView already supports pagination the same as ListView, except it's not super obvious how to make it work. You can try this by changing 'page=2' in the address bar of your browser while the filters are applied and sure enough it will go to the next correct page.

So to make it work is only a few steps...

Create a view mixin, which separates out 'page' keyword (default for django's pagination) and returns the remaining query string as a new template context variable.

```
class PaginatedFilterViews(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PaginatedFilterViews, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET:
            querystring = self.request.GET.copy()
            if self.request.GET.get('page'):
                del querystring['page']
            context['querystring'] = querystring.urlencode()
        return context
```

Then include this new object in all the FilterViews you want paginated... ie:

```
class FilteredList(PaginatedFilterViews, FilterView):
    model = Whatever
    paginate_by = 10 # or whatever
    # the rest of your view code
```

And update your pagination template to insert the rest of django-filter's query string...

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <li>
        <a href="?page=1{% if querystring %}&amp;{{ querystring }}{% endif %}">
            <i class="icon-page-first"></i>
            <span class="btn-text">First</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if querystring %}&amp;{{ querystring }}{% querystring %}">
            <i class="icon-page-back"></i>
            <span class="btn-text">Prev</span>
        </a>
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li class="disabled">
        <span class="icon-page-first">
            <span class="btn-text">First</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <span class="icon-page-back">
            <span class="btn-text">Prev</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    {# etc etc #}
{% endif %}
```

Works well for me across many views, and no other 3rd party dependencies are required.

Comment: Wonderful answer. I have little update. You don't need to work with GET parameters, you can retrieve query parameters from filter object, then encode them to url-safe form, e.g.: `context["querystring"] = urlencode(context["filter"].data)`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use django-tables with django-filter and that takes care of the pagination for me, so I'm no expert on this.  However it seems that you need to paginate the results of the filter once you have them in your view. Perhaps something like this?

```
paginator = Paginator(data, 10)
```

Check out this posting on SO. [Django Filter with Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546864/django-filter-with-pagination/51422501#51422501) and also this website explains how to do it generically. https://djangopy.org/how-to/pagination-with-django/

Answer (score 1):

late reply but I'll share my solution for future people.

I was having the same problem, both the django-filter, and pagination work properly on their own, but when combined it would only filter the first page.

This is because django-filters sends the filter parameters through with the request, and the pagination does the same. Therefore when you hit submit on the django-filter form, the parameters for your query get appended to the request. This might look something like:

'/?name=&project=&status=1'

Similarily, when you hit next page, you likely have it set up as a link which appends the page number to the request. Might look something like:

'/?page=2'

The solution I found is pretty hacky, but it works. What I did was read the request dictionary and create a string with the format: &{parameter_name}={parameter_value} to pass through the context, and append to the pagination links.

This loop looks like:

views.py

```
new_request = ''
for i in request.GET:
    if i != 'page':
        val = request.GET.get(i)
        new_request += f"&{i}={val}"
context = {...'new_request':new_request...}
```

You can then add this in your template at the end of the pagination link href:

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{{ new_request }}">Next</a>
```

This will preserve your filter selection through GET requests when going through pages.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had same trouble

what i saw...in this video
https://youtu.be/dkJ3uqkdCcY

you have to create a custom template tag...

like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iyh2.jpg)

And it worked for me...but with a fail....for example if i search only jobs in madrid..it shows the results of madrid...without mixing results...but the number of items its not 10 per page...i dont know why it shows 16...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).