# Making Pagination work with django-filter library and CBV

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-filter

I know a related question has been asked before here: 
[how can I use pagination with django_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389848/how-can-i-use-pagination-with-django-filter) but I really tried to make it work with mine but because I use a custom `LinkWidget` or class i find it hard to included the pagination in to  my `ResultsFilter` class or even get it to work with views and template.

Here is my code so far:

**filter.py**

```
# I didn't do much just changed so filters would be displayed as text/url just like django admin works instead of FORMS
# and i also add style to the returned <li>

class MyLinkWidget(widgets.LinkWidget):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self, **karg):
        # super().__init__()
        super(widgets.LinkWidget, self).__init__(**karg)
    def option_string(self):
        return '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark"><a%(attrs)s href="?%(query_string)s">%(label)s</a></li>'

class ResultsFilter(FilterSet):
    important = AllValuesFilter(widget=MyLinkWidget(attrs={"class":"list-group"}))
    viewed = AllValuesFilter(widget=MyLinkWidget(attrs={"class":"list-group"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Results
        fields = ['viewed', 'important',]
```

**views.py**

```
class ResultView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 3
    model = Results
    template_name = 'results_filter.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = ResultsFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

and finally template file is:

**results_filter.html**

```
<div class="filter_header">
  <span class="l">Filter by Viewed</span>
  {{filter.form.viewed}}
</div>

<div class="filter_header">
  <span class="l>Filter by Viewed</span>
  {{filter.form.important}}
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

## EDIT

So basically, when i am at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` it shows all records ignoring `paginate_by = 3` and i click next `url` becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2` but still showing all records. Which means pagination is not working but clicking filter for important or entering `url` as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/?page=3&important=False`. I noticed only data `i.e (20 records)` where `importance` is `False` are shown but i need just 3 page records so i can click next to view others.

Bottom line is i think `paginate_by` is not linked to the `queryset` returned by `Django-Filter` based on my classes above

Comment: What exactly is not working in your code? What is happening and how is that different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, as is easy to see with the code highlighting, your HTML is missing an closing quotation mark in the line `<span class="l>Filter by Viewed</span>` (the `class` attribute has no closing `"`)

Comment: @Ralf thanks pagination is the problem, I have added more information

Comment: [This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541540/9225671) suggests using an explicit `Paginator` on the filtered queryset

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but try this:

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView
    
class ResultView(FilterView):
    filterset_class = ResultsFilter
    paginate_by = 3
```

Then in you html use object_list, it will contain the paginated results.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
...
{% endfor %}
```