# How to filter items in query set without using {% for %} in django

Tags: python, django

I want to check of some field is exists in a query set that has many rows as result, here are the files

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    all_dress = Item.objects.filter(dress_active=True).order_by('-created_at')
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(all_dress, 12)
    try:
        dresss = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        dresss = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        dresss = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'dresss': dresss,
    }
    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/home.html', context)
```

the **context_processors.py** where i get my `user_Favs` query

```
def include_user_favs(request, user_favs=None):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        pass
    else:
        user_favs = Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context = {
        'user_favs': user_favs,
    }

    return (context)
```

And here is my **HTML** code :

```
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                               {% if user_favs %}
                      {% for item in user_favs %}
                  {% if item.item == dress %}
                                                      <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star-yes.png' %}" title="مسح من  الفساتين المفضلة"></a>
{% else %}
                                <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star_no.png' %}" title="إضافة إلى الفساتين المفضلة"></a>

                          {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                                              <a href="{% url 'favorite_item' dress.id %}">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/star_no.png' %}" title="إضافة إلى الفساتين المفضلة"></a>
              {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
```

I simply get a multiple result, as it uses the `for` loop to check on every item and if it found more that one item, it gives me more than 1 answer

Comment: It is not really clear to me what the problem is. You want it to only return *one* row? Which one should it pick if there are multiple?

Comment: yes the `user_favs` give me many rows, and I want to check everyone one from this rows and filter it .. but without using the for loop,, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure, but I'm assuming you're filtering down to only one object in your database but still receiving multiple.

In my experience, this is because pagination and filter sets sometimes have a hard time. 
Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048156/django-filter-use-paginations)