# Django View Return Queryset with extra information

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a normal Django view that returns the API for a query set. It takes query params from the URL and filters the database based on the parameters. It also outputs a maximum length of 3 "Part" objects.

I would like to add something so that it returns information on whether the queryset is clipped by the maximum length of 3. The idea is that since the inputs the query parameters, if the parameters are too vague, then there will be too much data being queried from the database. So it is clipped but then the user needs to know that it was clipped.

**The current code looks like this**

```
class PartList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PartSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Part.objects.all()

    querydict = self.request.query_params

    for (k, value) in querydict.items():
        search_type = 'contains'
        filter = k + '__' + search_type
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{filter: value})

    query_max_limit = 3
    return queryset[:min(len(queryset), query_max_limit)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch *four* elements, and in case it returns four, you display the *first* three, and specify that the data is clipped, like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Part.objects.all()

    querydict = self.request.query_params

    for (k, value) in querydict.items():
        search_type = 'contains'
        filter = k + '__' + search_type
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{filter: value})

    query_max_limit = 3
    qs = queryset[:query_max_limit+1]
    self.clipped = clipped = len(qs) > query_max_limit
    if clipped:
        return list(qs)[:query_max_limit]
    else:
        return qs
```

So here the `get_queryset` will return a collection (not per se a `QuerySet`), containing *at most* three elements, and it will set an attribute `self.clipped` that specifies if the data was clipped.

Or a more elegant approach would be to first count, and then slice:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Part.objects.all()

    querydict = self.request.query_params

    for (k, value) in querydict.items():
        search_type = 'contains'
        filter = k + '__' + search_type
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{filter: value})

    query_max_limit = 3
    qs = queryset[:query_max_limit+1]
    self.clipped = clipped = qs.count() > query_max_limit
    if clipped:
        return queryset[:query_max_limit]
    else:
        return qs
```

It might be better to move this "clipping" logic to a dedicated function, and return if it is clipped, instead of setting an attribute.

Comment: @user3759627: do not use the *queryset* itself, pass `self.clipped` to the context.

Comment: Why is "qs = queryset[:query_max_limit+1]" and not "qs = queryset[:query_max_limit]"

Comment: How do I access the self.clipped variable in the api view? I have this function inside my class

class PartList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PartSerializer

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to pass metadata along with your results, like so:

`{
    "is_clipped": true,
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}`

[Willem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740411/410963) is a good way to set `is_clipped`.

But I think you are interested in [pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagination), which is a standard way to communicate to clients that the results are clipped. It's possible [combine your queryset filering with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048156/django-filter-use-paginations). By the way, I suggest you use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html)  instead of rolling your own filtering.

Comment: I'm using React-Table to present my data. But I also want to clip the amount of data coming from the API because otherwise it can load too much data if there are not enough filter parameters to limit the amount of data