# TypeError: PaginationMiddleware() takes no arguments when trying to use django-pagination

Tags: django, pagination, typeerror, django-middleware, django-pagination

I'm trying to make `django-pagination` work with `django-filter` since I'm working with very large tables. But, after implementing it, when I try to do `python manage.py runserver`, I get a  TypeError: `TypeError: PaginationMiddleware() takes no arguments`

This is what I have done so far:

1. Installed django-pagination(1.0.7):

```
pip install django-pagination
```

2. Added it in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS= [....,'pagination',]
```

3. In my TEMPLATES in settings.py:

```
'OPTIONS':{'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.request'],},
```

4. In MIDDLEWARE in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [...,'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',]
```

5. In html file:

```
{% load pagination_tags %}
...
{% autopaginate filter.qs 40 as filter_list %}
{% for f in filter_list %}
...
{% endfor %}
{% paginate %}
```

I have all this, but when I try to do `runserver` I get the following error:

```
File "D..Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 36, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: PaginationMiddleware() takes no arguments
```

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

```
Django version: 2.1.13
Python version: 3.8
```

Edit: I was told in the comments that `django_pagination` doesn't support the newer Django versions. I have tried `dj_pagination` and `django.core.paginator` as well. But I couldn't make `django.core.paginator` work with `django-filter`

Comment: The last `django-pagination` release [was in 2010](https://pypi.org/project/django-pagination/#history). It won't support recent versions of Django, because of the switch from old-style middleware (`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`) to new-style middleware (`MIDDLEWARE`).

Comment: @Alasdair I see. Thanks for that info. I've tried using dj_pagination too. That gave me a bunch of different errors. Do you know of any other alternatives to paginate my results? I also used django.core.paginator but that broke my django-filter

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't have any recommendations. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048156/django-filter-use-paginations) might help you. If you want help getting `django.core.paginator` to work, then you should show what you tried and the full traceback of any errors.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for that! I just made dj_pagination work! I would've still been stuck at django-pagination if it wasn't for your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently I'm blocked from answering questions - but if anyone stumbles upon pagination and wants an easy solution, I ended up using dj-pagination. Very easy to use. Here's the [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/dj-pagination/latest/dj-pagination.pdf)