# Django Pagination by Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm implementing `pagination` based on a filtered `query`, it works okay before clicking on a page number but after clicking on a page number it shows all the objects including the ones which have not been filtered.
Started occurring after upgrading to the lastest version of django.

[image]
Pagination before clicking.

[image]
Pagination after clicking on page 2.

The `fitered objects` are `4` and given `2 items per page paginator` the pagination should stop at  `Page number 2` but it is showing a new paginator with all the objects even the ones not filtered.
Below are some snippets. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Views.py***

```
def searchPropertyListView(request):
 city = City.objects.all().annotate(
     num_property=Count("property")).order_by("-num_property")
 categories = Category.objects.all()
 purposes = Purpose.objects.all()

 featured = list(Property.objects.filter(featured=True))
 shuffle(featured)

 querySet = Property.objects.all()
 city_or_neighborhood = request.GET.get('city_or_neighborhood')
 category = request.GET.get('category')
 purpose = request.GET.get('purpose')

 if city_or_neighborhood != '' and city_or_neighborhood is not None:
     querySet = querySet.filter(Q(city__title__icontains=city_or_neighborhood)
                               | Q(neighborhood__title__icontains=city_or_neighborhood)
                               ).distinct()
 elif category != '' and category is not None:
     querySet = querySet.filter(category__title=category)

 elif purpose != '' and purpose is not None:
     querySet = querySet.filter(purpose__title=purpose)

 paginator = Paginator(querySet, 2)

 page = request.GET.get('page')

 try:
     querySet = paginator.get_page(page)
 except PageNotAnInteger:
     querySet = paginator.get_page(1)
 except EmptyPage:
     querySet = paginator.get_page(paginator.num_pages)

 context = {
     'city': city,
     'featured': featured,
     'querySet': querySet,
     'categories': categories,
     'purposes': purposes,
 }

 return render(request, 'search/search_list.html', context)
```

***Template.html***

```
            <nav class="mt-5">
               {% if querySet.has_other_pages %}
                <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                   {% if querySet.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{querySet.previous_page_number}}" tabindex="-1"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    </li>
                   {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    </li>
                   {% endif %}
            
                   {% for pages in querySet.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if querySet.number == pages %}
                     <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" style="height: 100% !important">{{pages}}</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link " style="height: 100% !important" href="?page={{pages}}">{{pages}}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                   {% endfor %}
            
                   {% if querySet.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ querySet.next_page_number }}"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </li>
                   {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item disabled">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </li>
                   {% endif %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution on this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048156/django-filter-use-paginations)

```
<nav class="mt-5">
{% if paginate.has_other_pages %}
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    {% if paginate.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{paginate.previous_page_number}}" tabindex="-1"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-left"></i></a>
    </li>

    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" tabindex="-1"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-left"></i></a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}

     {% for pages in paginate.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if paginate.number == pages %}
       <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" style="height: 100% !important">{{pages}}</a></li>
      {% else %}
       <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link " style="height: 100% !important" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{pages}}">{{pages}}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ paginate.next_page_number }} ">
        <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    {% else %}

    <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```